# R: XLConnect - RuntimeException (Java) : not implemented yet

Tags: java, r, runtime, xlconnect

Running R version 2.14.2.

When I use the XLConnect functions 'renameSheet' and 'cloneSheet', I get the following error:

```
> cloneSheet(wb,sheet="Data",name="Data_Old")
Error: RuntimeException (Java): not implemented yet

> renameSheet(wb,sheet="Data",newName="Old")
Error: RuntimeException (Java): not implemented yet
```

This other dude called Barry E. King has asked the same question elsewhere, and the only answer he's received is to ask the maintainer of XLConnect about it.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I installed the packages and their dependencies manually, as they are not compatible with the version of R I am running.

Comment: Which `XLConnect` version are you running? `packageVersion( "XLConnect" )`. I am running 0.2.5 and do not experience this problem.

Comment: I am using version 0.2.5 as well.

Comment: Things I'd be concerned about: that's a _very_ old version of R. It might not be the problem, but using a version of R that old would make me suspicious every single time something went wrong. Second, if your R version is that old, I wonder how old your Java installation is. You might try updating both.

Comment: Your workbook might use certain features that are not yet supported by Apache POI in a sheet cloning operation. You may want to try with XLConnect 0.2-7 - in case you get the same error you may want to check getOption("java.stacktrace") to find more information on the source of the problem.

Comment: Updated R and XLConnect to the latest version. Still facing the same problem. What should I be looking for in the stacktrace output?

Comment: You may want to post the stacktrace here such that we can see what the issue might be.